# Python Sqlite3 print specific data only from row

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Using sqlite3 I have a database with a single table with 4 rows(CI,BI,WIS,CO). What I am trying to do is get all the data out of the 4 rows based off data in row 0 (CI) and then only print the data in row 4(CO).
So in SQL it would be SELECT * FROM table WHERE row = ''
Now I can print the contents but I really only want row 4's data
The code snippet is what I have but cannot for love nor money print just the 4th row data. Any help would be super appreciated
'''

```
import sqlite3
def GetData():
    conn= sqlite3.connect("Boxes.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query ("""SELECT * FROM BoxTable WHERE CI = '001'""")
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchmany()
    print(data)
GetData()
```

'''

and the data will print

```
CI  BI  WIS  CO
001 A2  Nuts 245:134
```

I only need it to print CO

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basic SQL;

Change `*` (all columns)  to `CO` (that specific column)
... that's it.

Comment: Amazing thanks. That is all that it was.  it's always the easiest answer is the answer.